# MS Access, Is there any way to develop by more than 1 people?

Tags: git, ms-access

I would like to use version management such as GIT to Access Application.
I have got conflict issue on the Access Application which 2 people modify the code and then override each other modification.

Is there any way to use version management such as Git ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use, for instance, [this](https://github.com/timabell/msaccess-vcs-integration) version control system for Git

Comment: Thank you! It looks like what i want . I will have a lock!!!